# How to give a div oval shape?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I tried a lot on oval shape which have cut in both sides but not able to do it please [image]

I need code for oval shape with cut in both side..

Here's my code below:-

```
.demo{
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 178px;
    border-radius: 694px / 208px;

    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: You can use percent value for border-radius instead of pixels, see [Border-radius in percentage (%) and pixels (px)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966499/border-radius-in-percentage-and-pixels-px)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Is this OK ?

**HTML**

```
<div id="oval_parent">
    <div id="oval"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#oval_parent{
    background:black;
    width:200px;
    height:120px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#oval{
    width: 220px;
    height: 100px;
    margin:10px 0 0 -10px;  
    background: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    border-radius: 100px / 50px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/inuven/1/edit).

Comment: I didn't have time to write an example but this is what I was getting at 1+

Comment: @ Sheikh Heera i need both the back ground and oval in 100% width plz help

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of my home and replying from my cell but l'll try soon when I'll get back at home.

Comment: @Anudeep, [is this ok](http://jsbin.com/inuven/3/edit) or [this one](http://jsbin.com/inuven/4/edit).

Comment: @Anudeep, I think you have to define the size in `pixels` for making a oval shaped `div`.

Comment: @Anudeep, [here is another](http://jsbin.com/inuven/6/edit) but can't exactly make it without some fixed dimension, [here is another](http://jsbin.com/inuven/8/edit), just play with `radius`.

Comment: @SheikhHeera : can you explain what `100px / 50px` means ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#oval-shape {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    border-radius: 100px / 50px;
}
```

Notice the ratios in the corner values in relation to the height.

**Demo** - http://jsfiddle.net/XDLVx/

Answer (score 1):

Change the values on css:

```
#demo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 50% / 250px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40% / 250px;
    border-radius: 50% / 250px;

    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: or border-radius: 50% / 50% :)

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside another div which is high enough to show all the oval, not quite wide enough, and set overflow: hidden. If it's positioned at the centre the edges will be cut off, but you won't be able to side-scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible variants:

**Method #01:**

Use [`radial-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient):

```
background: radial-gradient(ellipse 65% 40%, transparent 0, transparent 90%, black 90%);
```

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(orange, red);
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
.oval {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse 65% 40%, transparent 0, transparent 90%, black 90%);
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval">

</div>
```

**Method #02:**

1. Create an overlay with `:before` or `:after` pseudo element.
2. Add `border-radius`.
3. Apply a large `box-shadow` with `overflow: hidden` on parent to hide undesired area.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(orange, red);
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
.oval {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.oval:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 500px #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: -10%;
  left: -10%;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval">

</div>
```