# Semi-oval with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to create a mix between an oval and a semi-circle.

Semi-circles can be created as such in CSS:

```
.halfCircle{
     height:45px;
     width:90px;
     border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     background:green;
}
```

And ovals can be made like this:

```
.oval { 
    background-color: #80C5A0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 100px auto 0px;
    border-radius: 200px / 100px;
}
```

But how can I make a semi-oval? Here's my attempt so far. The problem that happens is I've got flat tops, found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QGtzW/). Thanks!

Comment: it is posted here as well: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972145/how-to-give-a-div-oval-shape

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I've updated your demo with one possible solution:

```css
div {
  background-color: #80C5A0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50% / 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

By using percentage based units for the `border-radius` it should always keep a smooth semi-ellipse regardless of your `width` and `height` values.

With a few minor changes, here's how you'd render the semi-ellipse split in half vertically:

```css
div {
  background-color: #80C5A0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100% / 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Only chosen because you've given both ways to half the oval shape, but both answers from you and HerrSerker solved my problem - thank you!

Answer (score 5):

http://jsfiddle.net/QGtzW/4/

```
.halfOval { 
    background-color: #a0C580;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 100px auto 0px;

    /* top-right top-left bottom-left bottom-right */
    /* or from 10.30 clockwise */
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0/ 100% 100% 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use css3 [`radial-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) as well to draw this shape:

```
.halfOval {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 100%, #a0C580 70%, transparent 70%);
}
```

```css
.halfOval {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 100%, #a0C580 70%, transparent 70%);
  margin: 50px auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="halfOval"></div>
```