# Creating a Minion logo using Css

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes

I am currently trying to generate this as part of creating a full 'minion' from the famous Despicable Me films.

[image]

It's all going well, apart from the fact that I am trying to make the black section transparent (i.e. take the inner black section and make it transparent), so that the gradient colouring behind can be seen).

---

```css
.wrap {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: lime;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius:50%;
}
.logoWrap {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 15%;
  width: 200px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: black;
  transition:all 0.8s;
}
.logoWrap:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition:all 0.8s;
}
.logoWrap:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 160px;
  background: blue;
  border-bottom: 20px solid black;
  top: 10%;
  right: -40px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition:all 0.8s;
}
.wrap:hover .logoWrap{
  background:tomato;
  }
.wrap:hover .logoWrap:after{
   border-bottom: 20px solid tomato;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="logoWrap"></div>
</div>
```

---

So in my snippet i'm looking for the blue section to take the background colour.

---

**Please kindly note**

- The background colour will **not** be a solid colour (a gradient or texture instead).
- Using an image is out of the question
- Still working on 'bettering' the current logo, so a *alterable* solution would be preferred i.e. still able to change sizing quickly (no need to alter the 100 values of clip path)
- I would be interested in adding some animation/hover, so this would be reinforcing previous point

Comment: To be honest...it's interesting from a `fun to do` exercise point of view but I'd use an SVG instead...much simpler and no need for all those extraneous divs/pseudo-elements.

Comment: @Paulie_D: still haven't got round to SVG - still fine tuning css at present.

Comment: @jbutler483 when i make the circle transparent , i get the black diamond's background , not the green

Comment: @MohitBhasi: that *was* the reason I was asking.

Comment: @jbutler483 haha , ok i am trying my best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although an svg version of this would be better, you can achieve this shape with one element using box-shadows and pseudo elements :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/egLtf1jp/)**

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px; height: 400px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: 90px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:after,
div:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
div:after {
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  margin: 100px 0 0 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 
    -102px 0px 0px 100px #000, 
    140px 300px 0px 200px #000, 
    140px -330px 0px 200px #000;
}
div:before {
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  width: 250px; height: 30px;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: 63px -60px 0px 0px #000;
}
body {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-9.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

**EDIT :**

Here is an svg version of this shape with the `<mask>` element more suitable for "real life" :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/44pp01s1/)**

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
body {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-9.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<svg id="lbox" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <mask id="c">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="#fff" stroke-width="0" />
    <rect x="60" y="45" width="40" height="5" fill="#000" stroke-width="0" transform="rotate(-45 50 50)" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="18" fill="#000" stroke-width="0" />
  </mask>
  <rect mask="url(#c)" x="20" y="20" width="60" height="60" fill="#000" stroke-width="0" transform="rotate(45 50 50)" />
  <rect x="55" y="50" width="15" height="5" fill="#000" stroke-width="0" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is the closest thing you can get without SVG. In such situations SVG is the only choice.

### White portion transparent

This is the answer for the un-edited question (**1st** revision)

- I added `background: transparent;` **pseudoelement** and **main element**.
- I added `box-shadow` to **pseudoelement** and `overflow: hidden;` to main element.

```css
body {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/lDKpzMO.jpg);
  background-size: 40% 60%;
}
.wrap {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.wrap:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1000px black;
}
.circ {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 10000;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.circ:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1000px black;
}
.bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 120px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

### EDIT

For your updated question, i used a **psudoelement** and added a big box-shadow, a box shadow so big that its side became straight.

```css
body {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/lDKpzMO.jpg);
    background-size: 40% 60%;
}
div {    
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 80px;
}
div:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    top: 90px;
    left: 90px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: -200px 0px 0px 100px black,
        0px 200060px 0px 200000px black,
        0px -200090px 0px 200000px black;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    top: 96px;
    left: 150px;
    background: black;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: @jbutler483 think with me... Still, there are doubts about the growing influence of the css classes hinders the appreciation of the importance of the styles directions towards the code, otherwise its easier you use position:absolute instead of position:relative

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This does not work with the updated question (black section has to be transparent)

*This answer should be a comment (but I can't comment ;) )*

Have you tried mask? Here a great article about it: http://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

If you can't use it (targeted naviagator no supported), I'm afraid that you need to rethink the construction. If you can't use mask, the "transparent" has to be completely empty.
Maybe try to create and position 7 semioval and 1 rectangle. ([Semi-oval with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595147/semi-oval-with-css))

Here a picture with the highlighted part you should create.
[image]