# How to achieve this oval layout with CSS

Tags: html, css

How to achieve this layout with CSS?

[image]

Comment: show what you have tried?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/well-rounded-compound-shapes-css/  .      https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: the easy way is to set it as background... the hard way instead involves you trying something, instead of just asking for the solution.

Comment: These may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503636/transparent-half-circle-cut-out-of-a-div/30726390#30726390, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595147/semi-oval-with-css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this: https://jsfiddle.net/dqhx5cf5/

HTML:

```
<div class="rectangle"><div class="circle"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.rectangle{
   background-color: darkblue;
   width: 300px;
   height: 500px;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.circle{
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 600px;
   height: 600px;
   background-color: #ddd;
   position:relative;
   left: -150px;
   top: 100px;
   border: 2px dashed darkblue;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0px 5px #ddd;
}
```

**BUT with Firefox the curved line does not appear dashed because is not compatible with mozilla, but if you check it from IE and Chrome it works as well.**

Answer (score 1):

You can make shape like following way:

```css
.shape {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 150px 150px 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px;
}

.parent {
    background-color: #2e0854;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="shape"></div>
</div>
```

Learn more about shape from [here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your question. Hope it will be helpful.

Thanks

```css
*{margin:0;}
.container{width:400px;border:2px solid #666; height:400px;}
.main{background:#666; width:100%; height:200px; position:relative;overflow:hidden;}
.oval{background:#fff;width:100%;height:200px;position:absolute;bottom:-100px;border-radius:50%;}
.oval-dashed{background:#fff;width:100%;height:200px;position:absolute;bottom:-110px;border-radius:50%; border:1px dotted #666}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="main">
  <div class="oval"></div>
  <div class="oval-dashed"></div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it adopt to the container width (in this example the body):

https://jsfiddle.net/ehoo6pLt/9/

HTML

```
 <div class="elliptical-container">
     <h1>Content</h1>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.elliptical-container {
    margin-top: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    background: #EEEDEE;
    border-top-left-radius: 50% 75px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50% 75px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #EEEDEE;
    border-top: 1px dashed #3B2053;
}
```