# Make border-radius oval with Less and SimpleLess

Tags: less, css

I am trying to make an special border-radius, with an oval shape. In CSS I would do this:

```
border-radius: 10px / 5px;
```

But my Less compiler (simpless) take that and do the maths. What I get:

```
border-radius: 2px;
```

Anyone knows a solution?

Thank you guys :).

Comment: use border-radius: 100px / 50px;

Comment: @radha Doesn't that seem like a dirty hack to you?

Comment: see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972145/how-to-give-a-div-oval-shape

Comment: You should try border radius 50%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to define per corner radius:

```
border-top-left-radius: 10px 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px 5px;
```

You can get same effect without `/` sign. Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/a2SQW/1/

Answer (score 1):

[lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs): If you want to write a literal / expression without dividing in another property (or a variable), you can use [string unquoting](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#string_unquoting):

```
border-radius: e("10px/5px");
```

Comment: This also works on Visual Studio Web Essentials Less preprocessor.