# Create css wave form

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have been looking for a while to figure out how to recreate the below image forms in css but no source that leads me to a win.

The below image show what I'm trying to achieve
[image: style 1]

Comment: CSS is not a drawing program.

Comment: FYI Perfect ovals can be made with border-radius, 8 parameters and a slash in-between [SO oval shape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972145/how-to-give-a-div-oval-shape) (your shape is probable more complex here though)

Comment: @Rob, I know but it has plenty of awesome features since version 3. If it's possible to recreate an entire iphone in css why wouldn't this work?

Comment: @Maarten Too often people try to do this without realizing the consequences. May not apply to you or this but, on mobile, many attempts to do such things will bog down any phone. Sometimes the resulting code takes up more space than an image. Other times, more time and effort is put into making CSS do the work instead of just creating an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### CSS Gradients

This is possible with CSS gradients but I would really recommend using an SVG alternative as the lines in CSS will be jagged

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 55%, rgba(38, 155, 3, 1) 50%, rgba(38, 155, 3, 1) 56%, rgba(38, 155, 3, 1) 57%, rgba(38, 155, 3, 1) 58%, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 60%, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 67%, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 68%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 69%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 100%);
  background-position: -325px -5px;
  background-size: 700px 300px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### SVG

This is pretty close to what you are looking to achieve and with a little more co-ordinate moving it should be what you're looking for.

SVG is well supported and once you understand the methods and co-ordinate structure you can get things looking perfect and also have them be fully responsive.

```html
<svg width="100%" preserveAspectRation="none" viewbox="0 0 400 200">
  <path d="M0,5 Q400,40 400,90 L400,0z" fill="#8BC74A"></path>
  <path d="M0,10 Q400,20 400,80 L400,0 L0,0z" fill="#96292D"></path>
  <path d="M0,0 Q400,0 400,40 L400,0z" fill="#700810"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: nice one, but it seems every color circle has different radius in the above image.

Comment: @Mr_Green Looking into alternatives atm and gonna post an SVG version which is what i would recommend in a minute. This is ofcourse just a basic shape.

Comment: @Stewartside this is indeed almost what I'm looking for. Thanks for the great job, I'm about to start the tweaking on this thing!

Answer (score 2):

**Stewertside** has already shown the most apt. option, i.e. **SVG**, besides using an image.

Another option is **radial gradients** which victor and stewertside have shown.

Yet another option is **box-shadow**, which allows to create any no. of shadows, and also allows for their positioning.

**An example using box-shadow** and overflow hidden:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 200px;
  width: 820px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: -200px;
  top: 8px;
  box-shadow: 70px 70px 0px 70px #8BC74A, 35px 68px 0px 100px #96292D, 0 0 0 120px #700810;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah yes. My mistake! Edited!

Answer (score 0):

Look into overlying several elliptical gradients as background images:

```
background-image: radial-gradient(...),
                  radial-gradient(...),
                  radial-gradient(...);
```

Comment: In this case, why you not use SVG?